# Identifying multiple (graphical) object's edges from points

Tags: .net, image, image-processing, computer-vision, object-detection

I've got an application which is identifying motion in a webcam image. It produces something like the following...

[image]

Areas in black indicate motion. This is largely done on a per-pixel basis (although nearby pixels are taken into account)

So... Now that I've got a movement true/false for each pixel, I need to use that information to identify object outlines.

What I'd like is something like the following.

[image]

Outlines don't have to be precise and I could accept a bounding box. There are also some areas of noise which are more visible if I show you both combined...

[image]

As you can see there are a couple of "movement" pixels outside the objects. Presumably, I'd eliminate these by specifying a minimum area for an object.

So, what algorithm(s) are there for identifying the edges of objects. Ideally, I'd then be able to use this information to calculate the approximate center of each object.

Note: As mentioned by @mmgp, the images above are all full RGB, even the B&W one. This is due to the way I'm generating the image for export. Internally, it's a Bit array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a perfect task for Mathematical Morphology. To remove the small objects that, in this case, is a form a noise, perform a morphological opening by area. The area is easily estimated in your problem, as the interest regions are much larger than the unwanted ones. Now you also want to eliminate holes inside the large objects (notice there are some of these in your example). To do this you perform a operation that is called hole filling, which will simply discard those points that cannot be reached from the background of your image. At this point you can proceed to detect the centroids of your objects, but if you want to make the borders of your objects more uniform, you can use morphological dilations with small structuring elements or maybe morphological closing to possibly preserve more of the object.

These tasks are performed in Matlab as:

```
f = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/DexHs.png');
% The PNG is in RGB, but it actually describes a binary image.    
f = ~im2bw(f, 0);
g = bwareaopen(f, 100); % 100 is the maximum area for unwanted objects here
h = imfill(g, 'holes');
l = bwlabel(h);
cent = regionprops(l, 'centroid');
```

Which results in:

[image]

The two closed white curves are the boundaries of the remaining objects and in yellow you see their centroids. If you want a "softer" boundary as described in the initial comments of this answer:

```
h1 = imclose(h, strel('disk', 3));
```

[image]

I see you tagged this as .net, but I would expect these tools to be readily available in some .net package as they are very basic and common.

Comment: Now I notice I didn't comment about detecting edges in the answer. That is because it is not needed here. Given an object, the points that describe its border are trivially obtained as they are those which have contact both with the background and other points inside the object.

Comment: That looks like exactly what I need to do. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I have no idea if there's a .Net library which will allow me to do this or if I'll have to put one together myself but I'll have a dig and get back to you. My only real concern would then be speed (I doubt I'll be able to process _every_ frame but 1/second would be nice...)

Comment: These operations allow for very fast implementations. As frameworks go, I've heard of AForge (http://code.google.com/p/aforge/) for .NET but I have no idea of how good it actually is.

Comment: It seems there isn't specifically the area opening by morphology, but for your case, this: http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/features/blobs_processing.html is equivalent.

Comment: I'd avoided AForge in the past in favour of emgu (and OpenCV implementation) which has been faster in my testing but I think it's worth it for the functionality. Thanks very much for all your help

Comment: Ah, ok. If you aware of other frameworks, go with them. As I said, I have no idea of how good/bad AForge is. It was among the first hits in Google. If `emgu` is a wrapper over OpenCV, you will also be performing blob analysis to approximate this matlab code.

Comment: Yeah, I think in this case, it was just ignorance of what I approach I needed to take. Now I know, I can work out how best to implement it :)

Answer (score 1):

My advice is for you to use emgu (opencv) for those tasks, it is a bit more complex than matlab has you probably know, but it is faster.

OpenCV has **erode and dilate** morphology operations implemented for you:

http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=morphology#dilate

http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=morphology#erode

Or morphologyex suitable for more **generic morphology operations**:

http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=morphology#morphologyex

It also has the **findContours** function, you can think of it as a blob detector. In your case you could feed it your first image (probably after some noise-removing pre-processing) and it will return you those shapes. Those returned shapes are very easy to filter by area, if needed.

**findContours docs:**

http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=findcontours#findcontours

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll have a read through. I've managed to get it going using AForge but it's not as efficient as I'd like

Comment: Don't be fooled by this `morphologyex`, it is very far from being able to perform generic morphologic operations.

Comment: That's why I said "*more* generic". Ok that can be misleading, so what morphologyex can actually do are those 5 operations described in the docs (opening, closing, top hat, black hat, Morphological gradient) which are combinations of dilate and erode.